# AngularFireAuth error with ObservableInput

Tags: angular, rxjs, angularfire2, angularfire

I have the following code in my auth.service.ts which gives me the following error I cannot seem to fix:

Code

```
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';
import {AngularFireAuth} from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable, from } from "rxjs";

import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private auth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) {}

    canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {

      return from(this.auth)
        .take(1)
        .map(state => !!state)
        .do(authenticated => {
      if
        (!authenticated) this.router.navigate([ '/login' ]);
      })
    }

}
```

Error Message

```
ERROR in src/app/auth.service.ts(17,19): error TS2345: Argument of type 'AngularFireAuth' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ObservableInput<any>'.
      Property '[Symbol.iterator]' is missing in type 'AngularFireAuth' but required in type 'Iterable<any>'.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You're passing `this.auth` to `from`, which would expect something it can iterate rather than a service instance. Is there something in `this.auth` that should be passed rather than the whole instance?

Comment: To add to @R.Richards comment, I think you want the `of` operator, not `from` (which takes an iterable like an Array and emits each element one at a time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the `of` operator, which generates an Observable which emits once and then completes:

```js
return of(this.auth)
  .map(state => !!state)
  .do(authenticated => {
    if (!authenticated) this.router.navigate([ '/login' ]);
  })
```

If you upgrade to RxJS 6, you'll need to `pipe` your operators:

```js
return of(this.auth).pipe(
  .map(state => !!state),
  .tap(authenticated => {
    if (!authenticated) this.router.navigate([ '/login' ]);
  })
);
```